# The distance problem

Tags: kinematics, inertial-frames, relative-motion

Say a car has to move from **Point A** to **Point B** on the surface of the earth. The car starts from rest at **Point A** at time $t=0s$ reaches point B at time $t=10s$ with a constant velocity of $1000 m/s$. **Point B** is at a distance of **$x=10000m$** from **Point A** $x=0m$ (which is evident at the rest frame corresponding to the earth).

If I position my inertial frame which moves with the car at the same velocity ($10000 m/s$ in the rest frame) where my origin $(x=0m)$ always moves with the car, the car seems to be at the same position ($x=0m$) at time $t=0s$ and at time $t=10s$.

Does that mean the distance from Point A to Point B is $0m$ when observed from this moving inertial frame?

*I could sense that there is a logical flaw in my understanding, and any advice regarding the flaw would be greatly appreciated*

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the Points A and B with reference to the frame of Earth which is why you get a distance of 10000 metres. If you define the start and end point with reference to the car then you will surely get a distance of 0 metres. It would be like saying that the person didn't move *with respect to the car* from A to B as he was sitting in the car.